# How to display post's delete button for only post's author in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

Hello I've been stuck for days how to display a post's delete button only for the post's author in Ember.js (I'm using ember-cli to build this). I don't know where to put the logic of "**When hovering a post (list), if the post's author is equal to currently logged in user, then display the delete button**" I am lost. Please help me.

in template `app/templates/posts.hbs`

```
{{#each}}
  <div class="eachPost">
    {{#view 'posts'}}
    <div class="postProfilePhoto">
      {{#link-to 'users' }}
      <img src="" alt="Profile Photo">
      {{/link-to}}
    </div>
    <div class="eachPostContent">
      <p class="postAuthor"><strong>{{user.id}}</strong></p>
      <p class="postContent">{{body}}</p>
      <span class="timePosted"><em>somtimes ago</em></span>
      {{#if view.entered}}{{#if isAuthor}}   
        <a class="deletePost" {{action "removePost" this}}>Delete</a>
      {{/if}}{{/if}}
    </div>
    {{/view}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

in views `app/views/posts.js`

```
var Posts = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['eachPostContent'],
  mouseEnter: function(event){
    this.set('entered', true);
    this.get('controller').send('isAuthor', this.get('post').user);
  },
  mouseLeave: function(){
    this.set('entered', false);
  }
});

export default Posts;
```

in controller `app/controllers/posts.js`

```
var PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    ...
    isAuthor: function(user){
      if(this.get('session').user !== null && user === this.get('session').user){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
        console.log('You are not author');
      }
    }
  }
});

export default PostsController;
```

**SOLVED**

in `app/templates/posts.hbs`

```
{{#each itemController="post"}}
  <div class="eachPost">
```

created `app/controllers/post.js`

```
var PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isAuthor: function(){
    return this.get('user') === this.get('session').user;
  }.property('user')
});

export default PostController;
```

delete following code from `app/views/posts.js`
`this.get('controller').send('isAuthor', this.get('post').user);`

and deleted `isAuthor` function from `app/controllers/posts.js`

Comment: Did you try using an item controller?

Comment: Thank you @blessenm, I could solve it using `itemController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, you'll want to use an `itemController`

```
var PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   itemController:'post',
    ...
});
```

And then in the `itemController` you will create a computed property that checks the user id against the author id of the post

```
var PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isAuthor: function(){
      //assuming the user property exists on an individual post model
      return this.get('user') === this.get('session').user;
    }.property('user')
})
```